# how to speed up styling pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've just started developing and I'm working in a company that there is no senior developer to guide me ,How can I make sure that I'm in a right path I always doubt that my codes aren't good enough or I'm wasting time on styling pages using css ,if there is someone who can consult me I would appreciate.

Comment: There is a saying: "The worst developer is myself 1-3 month ago" so you shouldn't push yourself too much. A good way to learn in a private way is to check out "Code review" (also from stackexchange) or try to find an open source project to particiapte in.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't judge yourself**, A good programmer understands that he have to continue to learn and grow so just keep going. strive to do your best at every effort, admit to failures and learn from them. A good programmer loves to program, and would do so in their spare time even if they already spend 80+ hours a week programming.